# Scrapy - xpath query returns <li> list but only with first element repeated

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get all the li/a elements inside an ul tag with the following:

```
def parse(self, response):
    newItem = Item()
    list = response.xpath('//ul[@id="ad-list"]/li//a[@data-ds-component="DS-Link"]')
```

When I loop over the list, only the first element of each page I'm scraping is repeated over and over in the list:

```
   for item in list: 
        print(type(offer))
        newItem["product_id"] = item.xpath('//@data-lurker_list_id').get()
        newItem["url"] = item.xpath('//@href').get()
        newItem["title"] = item.xpath('//@title').get()
```

I already checked and I get the correct number of li in the ul as response in my list variable, but only the first li item appears.

To verify it after the response I tried to print the following:

```
    print("INFO:")
    print(len(offerList))
    print(list(map(lambda x: x.xpath('//@data-lurker_list_id').get(), offerList)))
```

I get this output:

```
INFO:
50
['1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301', '1204352301']
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem.
Basically should get only the ul, to get the list of li like I wanted.

```
list = response.xpath('//ul[@id="ad-list"]')
```